# A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I tried to create/run a basic JSP and ran into the following error.  I saw that other people have had similar problems, however, I haven't been able to find (or properly implement) a solution to the problem at hand yet.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SimpleServletProject]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SimpleServletProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HttpServletRequest
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1967)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 20 more

Jan 22, 2015 9:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Jan 22, 2015 9:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Jan 22, 2015 9:04:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 22, 2015 9:04:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 22, 2015 9:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jan 22, 2015 9:04:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 22, 2015 9:04:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Comment: What's the version of tomcat and `servlet-api` you are using? Without your application is deployed, the container starts correctly? Also, check `servlet-api`in `lib` folder.

Comment: All in all, this exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest` may be thrown, when server specific libraries like `servlet-api` are placed in the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Did you manually add such dependencies to your project.

Answer (score 12):

You must have packaged the `servlet-api.jar` along with the other libraries in your war file. You can verify this by opening up your war file and navigating to the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Ideally, you should not provide the servlet-api jar. The container, in your case Tomcat, is responsible for providing it at deploy time to your application. If you try to provide it as well, then issues arise due to version mismatch etc. Best practise is to just avoid packaging it. Remove it from the WEB-INF/lib.

**Additional Information**

If you are using maven for your packaging, then simply add the `provided` tag with the dependency and maven will make sure not to package it in the final war file. Something like

```
<dependency>
    <artifact>..
    <group> ...
    <version> ...
    <scope>provided</scope>
</<dependency>
```

Comment: Actually,the error is resolved but the problem I m getting is               Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.db.conec.Track, and Java type class com.db.conec.Track, and MIME media type text/plain was not found

Answer (score 12):

I faced similar issue and it was caused because I had written WebServlet Path in the .java file as well as in the web.xml . Removing it from any one location works fine for me.

In the .java file

```
@WebServlet("/index1.jsp")
```

and in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>tpc.Logout</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index1.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: This was problem for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your webapp has servletcontainer specific libraries like servlet-api.jar file in its /WEB-INF/lib. This is not right.

Remove them all.

The /WEB-INF/lib should contain only the libraries specific to the webapp, not to the servletcontainer. The servletcontainer (like Tomcat) is the one who should already provide the servletcontainer specific libraries.

If you supply libraries from an arbitrary servletcontainer of a different make/version, you'll run into this kind of problems because your webapp wouldn't be able to run on a servletcontainer of a different make/version than where those libraries are originated from.

**How to solve:**
In Eclipse 
Right click on the project in eclipse Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add library -> Server Runtime Library -> Apache Tomcat

Im Maven Project:-

add follwing line in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${default.javax.servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${default.javax.servlet.jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This answer was copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10556306/7155133

Answer (score 5):

Delete the project named Servers (or Servers1, Servers2 which contains your server.xml), find it in Package Explorer(workspace)

**Remove server from Eclipse :**
Go to Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment, here remove the server your are using from eclipse and add it again(doing this will create a new Server project folder in Eclipse) ,

**Remove server from Project :**
Also remove the server in your project(Build path > configuration path > Java Build path) and add again.

now you got a fresh Server project which will not have Multiple Context on its server.xml, only deleting duplicate path in server.xml solved the existing issue but still server dint start, by doing this Server started(Apache Tomcat v7) and  worked normal

And I don't know whether this is good practice or not, I am a starter in programming.

Comment: i just add and remove something in pom.xml and replace to original file, suddenly my workspace getting crazy.. after doing this step.. i manage to start the server... thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

I try with http servlet and I find this issue when I write duplicated  **@WebServlet** ,I encountered with this issue.After I remove or change **@WebServlet** value it is working.

**1.Class**

```
@WebServlet("/display")
public class MyFirst extends HttpServlet {
```

**2.Class**

```
@WebServlet("/display")
public class MySecond extends HttpServlet {
```

Answer (score 1):

check if you JAVA_HOME is set to 1.7 or below. because tomcat 7 is not compatible with jdk 1.8

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

1) add commons-logging.jar to the WEB-INF/lib folder

2) Add this jar as a maven dependency, e.g. add this to the pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

3) Maven install

4) Run the server.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with similar logs. I was using JDK 1.6 with apache tomcat 7. Setting java_home to 1.7 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some time this problem occur due to incompatible java version and tomcat version.Choose the compatible version of both.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. Changed the JRE to the correct 1.8 version and do a maven clean and build resolve the issue. You may need to change the Project Facet and verify the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

1. download **commons-logging-1.1.1.jar**.
2. Go to Your project,build path, configure build path, java build path.
3. Add external jars.. add commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
4. click on apply, ok
5. Go to project, properties, Deployment Assembly, Click on add,Java build path entries, next, select commons logging jar,ok,,apply, ok..
6. Delete server,clean ur proejct,  add server, Run your project.

Comment: i have same issue but your answer not solved to me

Answer (score 0):

Added AWS dependency and had this error. When I remove it from pom the error is gone. Probably you might have the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might also be caused by a broken Maven repository.

I observe the `SEVERE: A child container failed during start` message from time to time when working with Eclipse. My Eclipse workspace has several projects. Some of the projects have common external dependencies. If Maven repository is empty (or I add new dependencies into `pom.xml` files), Eclipse starts downloading libraries specified in `pom.xml` into Maven repository. And Eclipse does that *in parallel* for several projects in the workspace. It might happen that several Eclipse threads would be downloading the same file simultaneously into the same place in Maven repository. As a result, this file becomes corrupted.

So, this is how you could resolve the issue.

1. Close your Eclipse.
2. If you know which specific jar-file is broken in Maven repository, then delete that file.
3. If you do not know which file is broken in Maven repository, then delete the whole repository (`rm -rf $HOME/.m2`).
4. For each project, run `mvn package` in the command line. It is important to run the command for each project *one-by-one,* not in parallel; thus, you ensure that only one instance of Maven runs each time.
5. Open your Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed a similar issue in my project. The issue was solved when the jar with the missing class definition was pasted into the lib directory of tomcat.