# GWT Maps API V3 Core API

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gwt, spring-boot

I'm trying to use the `GWT Maps API V3` in a `Spring Boot` project.
I added it in `gradle` with no issue and wrote my code but when running, it crashes showing the following:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatResources$Tomcat7Resources.addJar(TomcatResources.java:125) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatResources.addClasspathResources(TomcatResources.java:63) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory$StoreMergedWebXmlListener.onStart(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:805) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory$StoreMergedWebXmlListener.lifecycleEvent(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:796) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatResources$Tomcat7Resources.addJar(TomcatResources.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Any idea how to use it with spring?

Answer (score 0):

From this [blog](http://crunchify.com/org-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception/), try coping `commons-logging.jar` file to `WEB-INF/lib` folder. You must also have packaged the `servlet-api.jar` along with the other libraries in your war file. You can verify this by opening up your war file and navigating to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Based from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28201344/5832311), you should not provide the servlet-api jar. *The container, in your case Tomcat, is responsible for providing it at deploy time to your application. If you try to provide it as well, then issues arise due to version mismatch etc. Best practise is to just avoid packaging it. Remove it from the `WEB-INF/lib`.*

Also according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556201/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-httpservletrequest):

> Your webapp has servletcontainer specific libraries like `servlet-api.jar` file in its `/WEB-INF/lib`. This is **not** right. Remove them all. The `/WEB-INF/lib` should contain only the libraries specific to the webapp, not to the servletcontainer. The servletcontainer (like Tomcat) is the one who should already provide the servletcontainer specific libraries. If you supply libraries from an arbitrary servletcontainer of a different make/version, you'll run into this kind of problems because your webapp wouldn't be able to run on a servletcontainer of a different make/version than where those libraries are originated from.