# Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start. traied All the version of tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have tried all the version but all fails

```
Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:onlineshopping' did not find a matching property.
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.8
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Apr 27 2018 19:32:00 UTC
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         9.0.8.0
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            6.1
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          x86
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\java
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_171-b11
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Akshay\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Akshay\apache-tomcat-9.0.8
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Akshay\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Akshay\apache-tomcat-9.0.8
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Akshay\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Akshay\apache-tomcat-9.0.8\endorsed
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\java\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/java/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/java/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/java/lib/i386;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop;;.]
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8180"]
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 731 ms
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.8
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:15 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@1988297]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@1988297]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4877)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:141)
        ... 34 more

    Jun 05, 2018 8:01:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:958)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
        ... 13 more

Jun 05, 2018 8:01:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

Jun 05, 2018 8:01:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8180"]
Jun 05, 2018 8:01:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jun 05, 2018 8:01:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Jun 05, 2018 8:01:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8180"]
Jun 05, 2018 8:01:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102134/a-child-container-failed-during-start-java-util-concurrent-executionexception)

Answer (score 0):

it has definitely something to do with your pom.xml in my opinion and below should solve it. Please try.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```