# Unable to start tomcat 7: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

My web project was running fine till yesterday however today when I start my tomcat server 7 it fails to start with below error in eclipse:

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CiscoQA_Automation_Framework]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1577)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1281)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5419)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1722)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
... 19 more
```

After referring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556201/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-httpservletrequest) and few other links I have cleaned up WEB-INF/lib and classpath and then added "log4j-web-2.3.jar" and "log4j-1.2.17.jar" in both WEB-INF/lib and class path. I have tried cleaning up the project and tomcat working directory as well nothing worked.

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on"          className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
```

Comment: I tried with "logback-classic-1.0.13.jar" and "logback-core-1.0.13.jar" jars as well but did not resolve the issue

Comment: are u using eclipse JUNO?

Comment: @holidayCoder: No, its Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a custom `<Listener>` in your `server.xml` that references a class that has a static dependency on Log4j, and you didn't add the Log4j jar file to Tomcats classpath, i.e. to the `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` (or `$TOMCAT_BASE/lib`) folder.

Either remove the listener or add the missing jar file.

---

**Update**

You say you added `log4j-web-2.3.jar` and `log4j-1.2.17.jar`, but the error message says that `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` is missing.

`log4j-1.2.17.jar` has a `org.apache.log4j.Logger`, so that's the wrong version of Log4j.

`log4j-web-2.3.jar` contains a `Log4jServletContainerInitializer` in package `org.apache.logging.log4j.web`. It is automatically loaded by Tomcat simply by being there. This is the class that needs `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`.

`org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` can be found in `log4j-api-2.3.jar`, so you need this file, but it is just the API. You also need `log4j-core-2.3.jar`, which is the actual Log4J 2 implementation.

If you don't have code using the Log4j 1 API, remove `log4j-1.2.17.jar`. If you do have code using the old API, replace that file with `log4j-1.2-api-2.3.jar`, which redirects old API calls to the new API. This eliminates the need for configuring both, and allow a single log file regardless of API version used.

*Summary:* You need the following files:

- `log4j-api-2.3.jar`
- `log4j-core-2.3.jar`
- `log4j-web-2.3.jar`
- `log4j-1.2-api-2.3.jar` *(replaces `log4j-1.2.17.jar`, only add if needed by old code)*

While you are at it, upgrade to the latest version (2.5).

Comment: I placed the log4j jar in "C:\XX\apache-tomcat-7.0.63-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\lib" directory and built the project again still same issue updated the question with the <Listener> in server.xml

Comment: Solved the problem, thanks. Would it be possible to give a overview on when and why this log4j jars are used?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this can happen when there are multiple log4j versions in your war and they conflict. If this is a maven build use mvn dependendency:tree to make sure that you are not transitively pulling in multiple versions of log4j. I'd start with looking in your $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/{your_app_name_goes_here}/WEB-INF/lib directory. I'd guess that the reason it stopped working today is because the class loader decided to load some other version of log4j today first.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the LifecycleListener interface in your program. Often it is particularly difficult to understand the cause of LifecycleListener problems, as there are generally numerous dependencies. My recommendation would be to scrap the contents of the file containing your LifecycleListener and to make sure to remove any decencies which may rely on it. Then reconstruct from the beginning.

This may not be the quickest route to fixing the error, but it is very likely to be be the most effective, and the one most likely to stop you from having further errors in future.

Comment: Note that the LifecycleListener is almost certainly not written by the OP, as the only change they described making is adding a third party library.  The library in question contains a LifecycleListener to configure the library and manage its resources.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFound error is generally not related to classpath issues so focussing there is futile. I recommend deploy ur web app in tomcat with default settings and then and customizations one by one to find the problem.

Comment: ... NoClassDefFound almost *always* is caused by classpath issues, i.e. a required class not existing in the classpath.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

`org.slf4j slf4j-api 1.7.21`