# I can't run java spring mvc project with tomcat and maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

when I'm trying to run my project, I get this errors:

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring]]
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>         ... 6 more
>     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scanWebInfClasses(TldScanner.java:401)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:208)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:106)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5261)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>         ... 6 more
>
>     авг 05, 2016 11:19:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
>     SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>         ... 6 more
>
>     авг 05, 2016 11:19:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>     SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
>     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>         ... 7 more
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>         ... 9 more
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>         ... 11 more
>
>     авг 05, 2016 11:19:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>     INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>     авг 05, 2016 11:19:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>     INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>     авг 05, 2016 11:19:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
>     INFO: Stopping service Catalina
>     авг 05, 2016 11:19:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
>     INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>     авг 05, 2016 11:19:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
>     SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
>
>     авг 05, 2016 11:19:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
>     INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>     авг 05, 2016 11:19:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
>     SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

This is the pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.javabegin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <name>TestMVC</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.3.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.8.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.21</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
</blockquote>
```

And web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Do you have any solutions ?
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556201/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-httpservletrequest Have you tried this?

Comment: Is the `</listener>` with a missing start a typo?

Comment: I've really forgotten <listener> but the same error