# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, integration-testing, maven-plugin

> Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/projectname]]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/servlet/ServletContext"
>
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]

In print stack trace it is not giving any `ClassNotFoundException :HttpServletRequest` also.

I have added tomcat maven plug-in in `pom.xml` file. I want to run some Integration Tests, so I added plug-in to run before integration starts. Here is my plug-in

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>8989</port>
        <systemProperties>
            <archaius.deployment.environment>test</archaius.deployment.environment>
        </systemProperties>
        <path>/${project.name}</path>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>tomcat-run</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <!-- We want test configuration for running integration tests. -->
                    <archaius.deployment.environment>test</archaius.deployment.environment>
                    <logback-lib.env>filesystem</logback-lib.env>
                </systemProperties>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

this plug-in I added in `pom.xml` file.

I also added `servlet dependency` and provided scope as `provided` only.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I do `mvn clean install` its giving following exception

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>       java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/projectpath]]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>         Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/projectpath]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>       ... 6 more
>         Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/servlet/ServletContext"
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationFilterAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:113)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       ... 6 more
>
> Sep 28, 2016 12:29:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
>        SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>         java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1238)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:592)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>         Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       ... 6 more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556201/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-httpservletrequest)

Comment: But there is no  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest in stack trace, I also added servlet dependency, how is it CLassNotFoundException?

Comment: For me it sound like a conflict with your servlet-api and the servlet-api provided by tomcat. What's your container tomcat 7 or 8 ? try 8 with your servlet-api 3.1 and set project facet Dynamic web module to 3.1. Or try to downgrade to 3.0.1 with tomcat 7.0.72 and facet 3.0. And the title of the duplicate question is wrong, the root cause of his problem was the same than you. I assume if you comment "tomcat7-maven-plugin" it works ?

Comment: externally I am not using any tomcat server, here I am using tomcat7 plug-In in pom.xml file.

Comment: I up you, edit your question with your environment I guess that could help.

Comment: that is what I posted.. I want to run tomcat internally, during maven build.. tomcat should get run before Integration test, thta's why I gave phases as 'pre-integration-test' and 'post-integration-test' . Do we have tomcat8 plug-in, I am searching for it but,couldn't find..
I am using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue,
actually `javax.servlet` was internally invlolved by other dependencies `http-lib` and `commons-util`.

I used

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
         <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

In both the dependencies. Then the problem was solved

Comment: I got the same problem but with another lib and resolve it just by exclude it ;) Thanks.