# Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I cannot run a Tomcat server. I've tried to delete the servlet parts from `web.xml` and the `org.eclipse.core.resources` folder but it didn't work.

Here is the log from eclipse:

```
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

sie 28, 2017 8:36:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sie 28, 2017 8:36:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
sie 28, 2017 8:36:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
sie 28, 2017 8:36:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sie 28, 2017 8:36:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556201/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-httpservletrequest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556201/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-httpservletrequest)

Answer (score -1):

> I Have similar problem, this solution is change the Tomcat port.

First.

Double click in Server.

[image]

Second.

In Modify the server ports change first 8 to 9.

[image]

Third.

Save the changes and Run.

[image]