# tomcat server failed lifecyclexception occured

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, lifecycleexception

I have recently bought a new system and I want to run a web project in eclipse on tomcat server. I have installed Java 10,eclipse photon,mysql, unzipped tomcat 8.5.32 zip file (i.e not installed tomcat as my guide told me that it is not necessary). Then I imported a project and created a server in eclipse, added tomcat in targeted runtimes. Then when I run that project on server error was displayed tomcat server failed , along with following error in console.Also I have mentioned JAVA_HOME,JRE_HOME,CATALINA_BASE, CATALINA_HOME in environment variable.Can anyone please tell me how solve the issue

```
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ntc_erp' did not find a matching property.
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 20 2018 19:50:35 UTC
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.32.0
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           10.0.1+10
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            "Oracle Corporation"
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         G:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         G:\apache-tomcat-8.5.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.32
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=G:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=G:\apache-tomcat-8.5.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.32
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=G:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.1/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.1/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1\bin;C:\Users\Pradeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\Pradeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\Pradeep\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;G:\;;.]
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 834 ms
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:34 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ntc-erp]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ntc-erp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@5afd708f]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4907)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5042)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@264cf2be]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.initDataOffset(ZipFile.java:1003)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:466)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:159)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readNBytes(InputStream.java:307)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:800)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:414)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
    ... 13 more

Jul 19, 2018 3:23:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Jul 19, 2018 3:23:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Jul 19, 2018 3:23:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 19, 2018 3:23:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/G:/apache-tomcat-8.5.32-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-8.5.32/lib/catalina.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: Did u search enough over the internet? Seems possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556201/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-httpservletrequest

Comment: The key line in your log extract is **java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)**, so you probably have an invalid war or jar file somewhere. The first thing to try is to remove (undeploy) your application from Tomcat, and then restart Tomcat. If Tomcat starts cleanly you know the problem lies with the project you deployed. Otherwise the problem may lie with your Tomcat download. Did you [verify the checksum/signature of your downloaded Tomcat zip file?](https://www.apache.org/info/verification)?

Comment: @rishi Your "internet" comment is unhelpful, and you might consider deleting it. Also, the question you link to is unrelated to this problem.